# Change Color of Selected Value in UIPickerView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have UIPickerView to display names using names Array

The first element of the array is default value "Select Name"

I want to display selected value in Gary color and rest of names in blue color

this func used to prevent selecting the default value:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if row == 0 {
        pickerView.selectRow(row+1, inComponent: component, animated: true)
        selectedName = names[row+1]
    } else {
        selectedName = names[row]
    }
}
```

and this func to change color

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = (row == pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(component)) ? UIColor.grayColor() : UIColor.blueColor()
    pickerLabel.text = names[row].name
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return pickerLabel
}
```

The problem is when I select the first value of the picker (not the default value), the color remains blue. All other items are working correctly (their color change to gray when I select them)

Answer (score 2):

[Use the PickerView reloadComponentMethod](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/reloadComponent:)

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if row == 0 {
            pickerView.selectRow(row+1, inComponent: component, animated: true)
            pickerView.reloadComponent(component)
            selectedName = names[row+1]
        }
        else {
            selectedName = names[row]
        }
    }
```

`selectRow` only spins the wheel to the new row. Calling `reloadComponent` refreshes the datasource to get new views

Comment: thanx but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 2):

I do this just before returning the value on `pickerView viewForRow` or `pickerView attributedTitleForRow`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1, execute: {
  pickerView.reloadAllComponents() // hack to refresh all values while scrolling
})
```

It's hacky but it works good enough for me. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var calendarContents : [[String]] = []

let dates = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
let months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR"]
let year = ["2015", "2016","2017"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    calendarContents = [dates,months,year]

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return calendarContents.count
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return calendarContents[component].count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let pickerLabel = UILabel()

    if pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: component) == row {
        pickerLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: calendarContents[component][row], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 26.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellow])

    } else {
        pickerLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: calendarContents[component][row], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 22.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white])
    }

    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    return pickerLabel
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
```